# Wordpress directory conflict: Need advice on htaccess paths

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am moving a website to Wordpress, and using the Multiblog functionality. I'm not a htaccess expert by any means, but I do manage to use it regularly. So I'm reaching out here for some expert advice.

The website, www.blather.ie will use the same path for the sub-blogs as the old website. I need to keep legacy folders - like www.blather.ie/zeitgeist and some of the old content while publishing a Wordpress blog to the same path. I realised when I tried to this that 403 error would occur. So I found a [workaround here](http://www.narga.net/how-to-solve-403-forbidden-wordpress-permalink-clash-folder-name/) and [here](http://jeffreybarke.net/2011/01/wordpress-permalinks-403-forbidden-error/).

Adding lines to my htaccess as described in those pages to my exist file didn't work. When I cleared out the htaccess file and started from scratch, I no longer got the 403 error - the content appeared, but without any themes/stylesheets. I checked the source, and saw that it was trying to pull the info from www.blather.ie/zeitgeist/wp-content... which doesn't exist - it needs to pull it from www.blather.ie/wp-content/...

Also, this 'fix' also started creating loops in the Admin back end. Not sure why.

So, here's my original htaccess file:

```html
# BEGIN WordPress

Options +FollowSymLinks
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

  
RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Here's the same htaccess with the recommended fix for the directory conflict problem, but which still causes the 403 error.

```html
# BEGIN WordPress

Options +FollowSymLinks
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Fix 403 errors on existing directories; WordPress overrides.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(zeitgeist)/ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]


RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Here's a "clean" htaccess taken from the 1st recommended website - it cures the 403, but breaks paths, points to the wrong stylesheet location and causes redirect loops and 403s in the backend instead:

```html
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
# Fix 403 errors on existing directories; WordPress overrides.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(zeitgeist)/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

**So - my question - where am I going wrong with paths, and causing these damn feedback loops?**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try this? Use the basic WP .htaccess, don't get fancy at all and instead drop a tiny .htaccess in each legacy folder (these are dirs right?) that disables rewrite in the folder.

This method worked for me as I needed to provide access to legacy folders as well.  There are some options you may need to hit with casual variations for environments. There are a few ways to do this such as disable rewrite, allow dir access, show details, etc so I can't include a snippet for you at this juncture.